# Masking a text field with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have searched for examples of JSON scripts to format a column output in a view and can't find anything for text field manipulation.

In Excel I would use this formula:

```
=concatenate("XXXXXXXXXX",right(*field*,4))
```

I'm a JSON newbie - any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below json:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "='xxxxxxx'+substring(@currentField,indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^')-4,indexOf(@currentField + '^', '^'))"
}
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Comment: Thank you Michael - that worked a treat. Very much appreciate your help.

Comment: You could accept my reply as answer if it hleps you:)